# Verticies aren't showing

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl-2

I'm having an issue with my code. There are no errors but nothing is being drawn. I'm not sure what's going on. What I'm doing wrong?

**Main.cpp**

```
//
//  MainGame.cpp
//
#include "MainGame.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "Errors.hpp"

// Constructor, initialize private variables
MainGame::MainGame() {

    _window = nullptr;
    _screenWidth = 1080;
    _screenHeight = 720;
    _gameState =  GameState::PLAY;
}


MainGame::~MainGame() {

    SDL_DestroyWindow(_window);
    SDL_Quit();
}

// Run the game
void MainGame::run() {

    initSystem();

    _sprite.init(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    gameLoop();
}

// Initialize SDL2, OpenGL, and whatever else
void MainGame::initSystem() {

    if (0 != SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nUnable to initalize SDL: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        fatalError("Unable to initiaize SDL");
    }

    SDL_LogSetAllPriority(SDL_LOG_PRIORITY_VERBOSE);

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ACCELERATED_VISUAL, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24);

    // Create the window...
    _window = SDL_CreateWindow("My Game",
                               SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                               SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                               _screenWidth,
                               _screenHeight,
                               SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL |
                               SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN  |
                               SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);

    if (_window == nullptr) {
        fatalError("Window could not be created");
    }

    SDL_GLContext glContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(_window);
    if (glContext == nullptr) {
        fatalError("SDL_GL context could not be created!");
    }

    // Clear to black
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    initShaders();
}

void MainGame::initShaders() {

    _colorProgram.compileShaders("/Shaders/colorShader.vert", "/Shaders/colorShader.frag");
    _colorProgram.addAttribute("vertexPosition");
    _colorProgram.linkShaders();
}

void MainGame::gameLoop() {

    while (_gameState != GameState::EXIT) {
        processInput();
        drawGame();
    }
}

// Process input with SDL2
void MainGame::processInput() {

    SDL_Event event;

    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {

        switch (event.type) {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                _gameState = GameState::EXIT;
                break;
            case SDL_APP_DIDENTERFOREGROUND:
                SDL_Log("SDL_APP_DIDENTERFOREGROUND");
                break;

            case SDL_APP_DIDENTERBACKGROUND:
                SDL_Log("SDL_APP_DIDENTERBACKGROUND");
                break;

            case SDL_APP_LOWMEMORY:
                SDL_Log("SDL_APP_LOWMEMORY");
                break;
        }
    }
}

void MainGame::drawGame() {

    glClearDepth(1.0f);
    //glClearColor(rand() % 255 / 255.0f, rand() % 255 / 255.0f, rand() % 255 / 255.0f, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    _colorProgram.use();

    // Draw sprite
    _sprite.draw();

    _colorProgram.unuse();

    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(_window);
}
```

**Sprite.cpp**

```
//
//  Sprite.cpp
//


#include "Sprite.hpp"

Sprite::Sprite() : _vboID(0) {
}

Sprite::~Sprite() {

    if (_vboID != 0) {
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &_vboID);
    }
}

void Sprite::init(float x, float y, float width, float height) {

    // Setup private vars
    _x = x;
    _y = y;
    _width = width;
    _height = height;

    if (_vboID == 0) {
        glGenBuffers(1, &_vboID);
    }

    float vertexData[12];

    // First triangle
    vertexData[0] = x + width;
    vertexData[1] = x + height;

    vertexData[2] = x;
    vertexData[3] = y + height;

    vertexData[4] = x;
    vertexData[5] = y;

    // Second triangle
    vertexData[6] = x;
    vertexData[7] = y;

    vertexData[8] = x + width;
    vertexData[9] = y;

    vertexData[10] = x + width;
    vertexData[11] = y + height;

    // Bind vertex buffer object
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vboID);

    // Upload to GPU
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexData), vertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Unbind
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

}

void Sprite::draw() {

    // Bind buffer
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vboID);

    // Use first attribute array
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    // Point data to VBO
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    // Draw 6 verticies to screen
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

    // Disable vertex attribute array
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

    // Unbind VBO
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to provide code instead of links.

Comment: Also, an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will help us and maybe it'll help you, too.

Comment: Since this is a OpenGL 4.1 Core Profile, you have to use a VAO.

Comment: Thank you @Damian for editing my post and thank you very much @BDL! I looked up VAO and added it. Now it's working perfectly!

Comment: @BDL For later reference to other users, please consider adding your solution as a reply rather than a comment! :)

Comment: @TormodHaugene: Already done...

Comment: @BDL Best avoid posting answers as comments at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OpenGL > 3.3 Core Profile, the usage of a VAO is mandatory.

Normally this gives you a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error on the draw command (has to be queried by `glGetError()`)